# Touchpad and Keyboard get freezed at login screen in ubuntu12.04

Tags: keyboard

I dual booted Ubuntu with window7.

> After few days of usage, when I boot into Ubuntu both my touchpad and keyboard freeze.

Apart from that, Bluetooth is set visible, the icon shows but can't find phone in both OSs.But touchpad and keyboard work well in Windows7.
I was asked to change something in etc default grub, but how do I do this when it freezes at the login screen.
If you can assure me that a usb keyboard and mouse will work.I will buy.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your computer seems to be an issue maybe your ram got overloading, It should not be a problem with grub because that is just a bootloader. If restarting worked. Run the commands below

`sudo apt-get install preload`

The command above preloads everything into your memory.